# How to read configuration files in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

I have a standard maven project layout.
Some configuration files are stored in `src/main/conf`.
Now I would like to read these files in my unit test in `src/test` (e.g. read a properties from one of those files).
How can I exactly do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's stopping you from reading them in your test the same way they are read in production code? Are you getting some kind of error message when you try?

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure maven to use these files as test resources.

Just specify it in `pom.xml`. Than maven will handle your configuration files same as test resources.

```xml
  <build>
    ...
    <testResources>

      <!-- don't forget to specify the default test resources directory -->
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>

      <!-- add the config directory -->
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/main/conf</directory>
      </testResource>

    </testResources>
    ...
  </build>
```

This settings will force maven to copy configuration files to `target/tests-classes` before running unit tests.
Then your unit tests will have configuration files on classpath and you can read them using `getClass().getResource("/yourConfigFile.conf")`.

Comment: It's far simpler to just put the files in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`.

Comment: I prefer my way. You can more express the purpose of the resource. And it's simpler to additional configuration like filtering.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, I found the surefire-plugin prevents the files under src/test/resources to be copied into the target/test-classes

Answer (score 2):

You should put such files in `src/main/resources`, so they will be included on the classpath and accessible through `this.getClass().getResourceFromStream("...")`.

Edit: As bbaja42 says, if they're only used for tests they should go in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Shouldn't test configurations go to `src/test/resources` ?

Comment: @bbaja42: They certainly should, but i assumed these are configuration files used outside the tests as well.

Comment: He could set up the resources in the pom so that the test stuff also looks in `src/main/resources` to avoid having (possibly conflicting) copies of the resources.

Comment: @keith.layne: `this.getClass().getResourceFromStream("...")` looks on the class path, which in the tests contains both `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`. There's nothing special to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing Christoffer's answer, in order to access src/main/conf within your tests you need to add that folder to your maven-surefire-plugin classpath configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    .....   
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>src/main/conf</additionalClasspathElement>           
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

....

Then you'll be able to load files from classpath. Suppose a file as src/main/conf/test.txt:

this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")

In order to run this inside Eclipse you also need to add that folder to your build path as well.

You can find more info at: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

Comment: It's far simpler to just put the files in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`.

Comment: I agree, but this is just in case you need another folder in the classpath; could be something from legacy or you need to share / access a folder from your production configuration for some other reason. The documentation also does not recommend adding custom jars/resources to the classpath.

Comment: The sneaky thing for me was that the / seems to be required in `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")`. Doing `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt")` would not work for me. This was not entirely obvious initially.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, I found the surefire-plugin prevents the files under src/test/resources to be copied into the target/test-classes